# Create remarketing list in adwords using nodejs

Tags: google-ads-api

I didn't find how to create audience in "Google AdWords" using Node-JS.
Does anyone have an idea?

I am searching for something similar to this in Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/v2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page details how you can create user lists and assign them as criterion to your adgroups. Unfortunately it might be hard to find prewritten node examples, but it should translate pretty easily to the library you are using.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/remarketing

Comment: Thank you. But this is in Java

Comment: Yeah I acknowledged that above. You probably won't find prewritten node examples. They do have a JS adwords library. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/ There aren't examples for everything there. Have you developed on any part of the API yet or are you just beginning?

Comment: I am start from the beginning. What you sent me is last updated at 2011, I cannot trust it.

Comment: Using Node with this is going to be difficult to start with if you don't have much prior experience with the API's. There isn't a client library for NodeJS as far as I can see that is being maintained. You are going to have to write everything by hand :/

Comment: I have lot of exprience with NodeJS and other API`s. I just search for documentation for this REST

Comment: The guide i gave you here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/remarketing includes links to the resources that you will need to make calls to. The API isn't REST based, it's all SOAP based. You can read some more information about that in a discussion here: http://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Google-develop-REST-API-for-AdWords